# Poner una imagen y un texto en la misma línea

Tags: html, css

Necesito que estén a la misma altura la foto y el texto donde pone "ONE MORE SHOT". He probado poniendo el margin de la y imagen y del texto a 0 pero no me ha funcionado. Adjunto captura de como está actualmente y el código:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
   .headerEnd{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#000000;
    height:110px;
   }
   #fotoEndi{
    margin-left: 100px;
   }
   
   @font-face{
    font-family: "TituloEndi";
    src: url("GameofBrush.ttf");
   }
   a:link{
    text-decoration:none;
    
   }
   a:visited{
    color: #000000;
   }
   
   #nombreEndi{
    text-align: center;
    margin:0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    color: #8B0000; 
    font-family: "TituloEndi";
    font-size:40px;
   }
   
   .header{
    height:100px; width:100%;
    text-align:center;
   }
   
   .menu{
    height: 37px;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #B22222; 
    color:#333; 
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow:0px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0)
   }
   .wrapper{ height:2000px; 
      width:100%; 
      padding-top:20px
   }
   .menu-fixed {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1000;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #999;
   }
   ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block; 
    font-size: 25px;
    width: 100%;
   }
   
   body{
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
    margin: 0;
   }

   #menu li{
    background: #DCDCDC;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    background-color:#B22222;
   }
   
   .listaArriba{
    color:  #000000;
    width: 150px;
   }
   
   #titulua{
        background-color:#000;
     text-align:center;
     margin-left: 300px;
     margin-top: 7px;
   }
   
   .seccion1{
    background-color: white;
    height:749px;
    width: 1350px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
   }
   #footer{
    margin-top:0px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color:#B22222;
   }
   
   #soundcloud{
    margin-right:40px;
    margin-top: 3px;
   }
   .navigationFoot{
    text-align: right;
   }
   #creditos{
    font-size:12px;
    text-decoration:none;
   }
   a{
    color:black;
   }
   #o{
    margin-left: 250px;
    float: top;
   }
   
   .videos{
    height: 500px;
    width: 1000px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
   }
   
   #oneMoreShot{
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 20px;
   }
   
   #oMSmin{
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    border: 4px solid;
   }
```

```html
  <header class="headerEnd">
   <div class = "cabecera">
    <ul id = "lista1">
     <a href="home.html" id="fotoEndi"><img src="endikasangroniz.png" id=titulua></a>
     <a href="../EndiIngles/endi.html" id = "o"><img src="../Bandera/uk.png"></a>
     <a href="../EndiCastellano/endi.html"><img src="../Bandera/banderaEspana.png"></a>
     <a href="../EndiEuskera/endi.html"><img src="../Bandera/ikurrina.png"></a>
     
    </ul>
   </div>
  </header>
  <header class = "header">
   <div class="menu" id="menu">
    <nav class="top-menu">
     <ul class = "navigation">
      <li class="listaArriba" id="news"><a href="news.html">NEWS</a></li>
      <li class="listaArriba" id="conciertos"><a href="gigs.html">GIGS</a></li>
      <li class="listaArriba" id="videos"><a href="videos.html">VIDEOS</a></li>
      <li class="listaArriba" id="songs"><a href="music.html">MUSIC</a></li>
      <li class="listaArriba" id="lyrics"><a href="lyrics.html">LYRICS</a></li>
      <li class="listaArriba" id="store"><a href="https://endikasangroniz.bandcamp.com/" target="_blank">STORE</a></li>
     </ul>
    </nav>
   </div>
    
    <div class="videos">
     <section>
      <img  id="oMSmin" src="../CaratulasAlbum/oneMoreShotmin.jpg"/> <h1>ONE MORE SHOT</h1>
     </section>
     
    </div>
    
    
    <div id="footer">
     <ul class = "navigationFoot">
      <a id="n" href="https://es-es.facebook.com/EndikaSangroniz/" target="_blank"><img src="../IconosRedes/iconoFacebook.png" ></a>
      <a id="n" href="https://www.instagram.com/endikasangroniz/?hl=es" target="_blank"><img src="../IconosRedes/iconoInsta.png"></a>
      <a id="n" href="https://endikasangroniz.bandcamp.com/" target="_blank"><img id="soundcloud" src="../IconosRedes/bandcamp.png"></a>
     </ul>

   </div>
  </header>
```

Adaptando el código a la solución de otro hilo parecido:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Parecido, pero yo uso etiquetas h y no p. No sé si comparten propiedades. En ese caso si sería un duplicado.

Comment: @MikelMolinuevo no tiene nada que ver que etiqueta uses, las propiedades css las mismas puedes aplicar a ambas etiquetas

Comment: He probado lo de ese hilo y sale demasiado arriba el texto. No es válido.

Comment: actualiza la pregunta, añadiendo el nuevo problema y tambien es recomendable solo añadir solo el código relevante y tal vez una imagen de ejemplo para el fiddle

Comment: Ya está actualizado.

Comment: El texto te queda arriba por que a la imagen le estás dando un `margin-top: 50px;` simplemente quita ese margin o agrégalo también al `<h1>`, hazlo y me cuentas

Comment: Ha funcionado. Gracias. Si lo pones como respuesta la marcaré como tal.

Comment: Claro ya te la publico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El texto te queda más arriba por que a la imagen le estás dando un `margin-top: 50px;` simplemente quita ese margin o agrégalo también al `<h1>` para que puedan quedar a la misma altura.

**SOLUCIÓN 1: Quitar `margin-top` a la imagen**

```
#oMSmin{
    margin-left: 80px;
    border: 4px solid;
}
```

**SOLUCIÓN 2: agregar `margin-top` al título**

```
.videos section h1{
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```